# MVC drop down list - null error

Tags: model-view-controller

I have generated Models classes using Entity Framework.
This is what I got:

```
public partial class Employees
{
    public Employees()
    {
        this.Employees1 = new HashSet<Employees>();
        this.Vacations = new HashSet<Vacations>();
    }

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public int ManagerID { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employees> Employees1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Employees Manager { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Vacations> Vacations { get; set; }
}
```

Then I've created View Model for that class:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public int ManagerID { get; set; }
    public string ManagerFullName
    {
        get
        {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }

    }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employees> Employees1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Employees Manager { get; set; }


}
```

In EmplyeeControler class I have action:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    EmployeeViewModel employeeVM = new EmployeeViewModel();
    ViewBag.Employees1 = new SelectList(employeeVM.Employees1, "EmployeeID", "ManagerFullName");
    return View(employeeVM);
}
```

And view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManagerID, "Manager")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("ManagerID", "--- Select Manager ---")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManagerFullName)
</div>
```

But I am receiving error on line:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items

```
 ViewBag.Employees1 = new SelectList(employeeVM.Employees1, "EmployeeID", "ManagerFullName");
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: How will MVC know `ViewBag.Employees1` must be used? Use `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ManagerID, ViewBag.Employees1, "--- Select Manager ---")`.

Comment: It doesn't work. The same error occurs. Why you wanted to make change in View when the error occurs in Controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManagerID, "Manager")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ManagerID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Employees1,"--- Select Manager ---"));
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManagerFullName)
</div>
```

More Details  See this [link](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/08/bind-dropdownlist-in-dotnet-mvc-razor.html)